# Does this query make sense?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I recently migrated a database from Sybase ASE to Microsoft SQL 2008r2.
One category of queries that was broken in transit is:

```
SELECT person_id
  FROM leaveperiods
 WHERE group_id=146
 GROUP BY person_id
HAVING start_date = max(start_date)
```

According to Sybase, this is a valid query. But Microsoft SQL is stricter, so I get this error:

```
Column 'leaveperiods.start_date' is invalid in the HAVING clause
because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

While looking at this query to try and correct it, I realized that it does not make sense to me. Isn't this exactly the same as the below?

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_id
  FROM leaveperiods
 WHERE group_id=146
```

Or maybe I should write like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_id
  FROM leaveperiods
 WHERE group_id=146
   AND start_date IS NOT NULL
```

There are several queries like this in one application and I need to fix them without breaking anything else. Please help.

Comment: Are you just trying to find the people with the highest start date for that group? Can you show some sample data and desired results? Also I suggest making a more descriptive title. "Does this query make sense?" is meaningless and could apply to any query-related question on the site.

Comment: The "trying to do" I don't know. There is this big web-based PHP application that worked ok in Sybase, and was issuing this query.
So what I actually try to do is to reproduce the same behaviour of this query, in a way that is accepted by Mssql.
Then there is the personal learning part, I am trying to understand if there is something in this query that I don't understand.

Comment: Actually even with the Sybase non standard [`GROUP BY`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug113.htm) it doesn't make sense to me that you would `SELECT` the same column as you are grouping by with that `HAVING` clause.

Comment: That was my impression too.

Comment: I think MSSQL might require any columns in your "having" clause to be in your grouping, so I think you might have to change your grouping clause to `GROUP BY person_id, starte_date`, but I'm not sure (I don't have MSSQL in front of me now to verify this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand the semantics of the Sybase non standard `GROUP BY` a purely mechanical rewrite would be.

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT person_id,
                start_date,
                MAX(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id) AS max_start_date
         FROM   leaveperiods
         WHERE  group_id = 146)
SELECT person_id
FROM   T
WHERE  start_date = max_start_date
```

But the query does seem odd.

#### [Documentation Extract](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug113.htm)

> For example, many versions of SQL do not allow the inclusion of the
>   extended `title_id` column in the select list, but it is legal in
>   Transact-SQL:
>
> ```
> SELECT type,
>        title_id,
>        avg(price),
>        avg(advance)
> FROM   titlesgroup
> GROUP  BY type
> ```
>
> The above example still aggregates the price and advance columns based
>   on the type column, but its results also display the `title_id` for the
>   books included in each group.

```
+--------------+----------+------------+--------------+
|     type     | title_id | avg(price) | avg(advance) |
+--------------+----------+------------+--------------+
| mod_cook     | MC3021   | 11.49      | 7,500.00     |
| UNDECIDED    | MC3026   | NULL       | NULL         |
| popular_comp | PC1035   | 21.48      | 7,500.00     |
| popular_comp | PC8888   | 21.48      | 7,500.00     |
| popular_comp | PC9999   | 21.48      | 7,500.00     |
| psychology   | PS1372   | 13.50      | 4,255.00     |
| psychology   | PS2091   | 13.50      | 4,255.00     |
| psychology   | PS2106   | 13.50      | 4,255.00     |
| psychology   | PS3333   | 13.50      | 4,255.00     |
| psychology   | PS7777   | 13.50      | 4,255.00     |
| trad_cook    | TC3218   | 15.96      | 6,333.33     |
| trad_cook    | TC4203   | 15.96      | 6,333.33     |
| trad_cook    | TC7777   | 15.96      | 6,333.33     |
+--------------+----------+------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The original query looks like an attempt to find the person in Group 146 who most recently began a leave.  If that's the case, this should work:

```
SELECT TOP 1 person_id
FROM leaveperiod
WHERE group_id = 146
ORDER BY start_date DESC;
```

Comment: No, the original query returns several rows.
I trust the application to work ok with Sybase, so the result must return several person_id's

Comment: Ah yes, there could be multiple people sharing the honor of having started leave most recently of those in Group 146.

Comment: I don't think these are the correct semantics anyway. It seems you assume that the Sybase behaviour is akin to `WHERE start_date = MAX(start_date) OVER ()` but it seems from the docs to be more like  `WHERE start_date = MAX(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id)`

Comment: I believe you are correct.  I jumped to the conclusion that the first was correct because that way the query makes sense.  If the behavior really is `MAX(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id)` then the original query seems to be just a tortuous way of getting `DISTINCT person_id` for that group in the table.

Comment: @mdoyle - But excluding those ones for which there doesn't exist a non null `start_date` and including multiple rows for a `person_id` if there are multiple rows matching the `MAX(start_date)` (though there may be constraints that mean neither of these are possible)